# Reference request for a theorem of Brauer regarding representations of a finite group

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory

In the representation theory of finite groups in characteristic 0, we have that the group ring completely decomposes into a product of matrix algebras once tensored with $\mathbb{C}$, and similarly over any algebraically closed field of characteristic 0.

I recall reading somewhere that it is a (deep) theorem of Brauer that the group algebra decomposes completely over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{|G|})$, where $\zeta_{|G|}$ is a primitive $|G|$th root of unity.

Does anyone have a reference for this result, and/or an idea of the techniques used in the proof?

Comment: I seem to remember this is in Lang's *Algebra*.

Comment: Yep, it was in there, thanks.